# Build query (boolean) function for pandas loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [20, 51, 34, 41, 44]})` and a dict structured like this `{'A': {'operator': '<', 'value': 40}}` from which we want to select data in the same way loc does that, for this example that is:
`df.loc[df['A'] < 40]`

We can try this by building a string query:

```
def build_query(set_values, df):
    query = ''
    for value in set_values:
        query = f"{query} and {value} {set_values[value]['operator']} {set_values[value]['value']}"
    return query[5:]
```

and then run it with the `.query()` function like this: `df.query(build_query({'A': {'operator': '<', 'value': 40}}, df))` which gives us the correct selection, but we can't manipulate it in such a way as we can with `.loc` as trying to set a value of this specific selection (by doing `df.query(build_query({'A': {'operator': '<', 'value': 40}}, df))['A'] = 0`)  we get: *A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.* It is possible to loop through the results and assign A, though for a large dataframe this takes too long.

Is there a way we can make `build_query` get to work with `.loc`?

Comment: Can you use a for loop on the selection and then assign the value for 'A' that way?

Comment: That is possible, though with a large dataframe this takes way too long. I do prefer `.loc`

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output. easier to reason and proffer a solution, if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use `reduce` and `and_` to chain your conditions with `pd.eval`:

```
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce

d = {'A': {'operator': '<', 'value': 40}}

print (df.loc[reduce(and_, [df.eval(f'{k}{v.get("operator")}{v.get("value")}')
                           for k,v in d.items()])])

    A
0  20
2  34
```